# How to change pdf image Color on swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I added a button and set a pdf image. I need to change the pdf image color. can to do it?

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this extension method to set image color,

```
import UIKit

extension UIButton {

    public func setImage(color: UIColor, for state: UIControl.State) {
        let image = self.image(for: state)
        self.setImage(image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: state)
        self.tintColor = color
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
yourButton.setImage(color: .red, for: .normal)
```